# How secure is this GWT/RPC security method for a GWT GAE Java App?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

Once a user is logged in, I create a Java session and store their userid and sessionid (sid) in the session, these two parameters are sent to GWT client and they are stored there in a base GWT client presenter (not as cookies). I am using MVP Architecture.

Every call made to sever there after is sent with these two parameters userID and SID, so I verify this on server, that the current session on server is equal to the session id provided and it belongs to given userid.

IF all is OK, only then I process the RPC request further.

Also, I am planning to make all my RPC handlers to extend a common RPC Handler which will accept these parameters.

I am new to GWT and GAE, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I would stay away from sessions on GAE, They are expensive. I would store session info in client and pass it back and forth as needed.

Comment: does storing the userid and the sessionid give you any benefit over storing just the sessionid?  shouldn't a sessionid map to only one userid in the server?

Comment: Hi Peter, you are right, thats my intention, but my implementation isn't correct. Can u please tell me how to map a user ID with a session that was created in java/GAE?

Comment: Hi Romain, you may be right. For my application, I have multiple channels in which users connect to the server, eg. Mobile, web services, etc. So I thought a session on server is surely going to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SSL and sending the session ID in the payload of every request are two good first steps. This [LoginSecurityFAQ](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/LoginSecurityFAQ) provides a good explanation with more details.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone that can intercept the traffic on the wire/airwaves can take control of the user's session UNLESS you're sending session state over ssl/https.